# Error: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-4, iis-7.5

I have developed a web application (ASP.NET, Entity Framework 4, .NET 4, IIS 7.5). The application works fine on my machine. When I deployed it on the production server, I got the following error in some pages:

```
Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
```

After some Google search, I made sure that I set the "Copy Local" option in Visual Studio to True for all References. Also, on IIS, I made sure that the application is on Full Trust.

Now, this error is strange. Sometimes it solves itself! when I redeploy the application on the web server it works fine. After a while, I get this error again !!!

Please help! I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution ..

it seems that when using multiple EntityFramework DataSources (for use with drop downs for example) you get this error.

I removed all the EF Data Sources from my page and did the data binding in the code behind.

solved the problem